# JQuery Events AutoTrigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quick question, If I use the following line of code it Auto triggers the event:

```
$(document).on('submit','#site-search',searchOperator.controller.searchStart(searchOperator.model.page));
```

However this does not Auto tigger:

```
$(document).on('submit','#site-search',searchOperator.controller.searchStart);
```

Any Ideas as to why it Auto triggers the event when I pass a variable to the event function.

Edit: When I say Auto Trigger I mean the event fires, when the page loads.

Comment: Adding the parenthesis calls the function, just using the name of the function references the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass in a variable to the function, it invokes the function immediately. When not passing a variable, your passing the function as an argument to be executed when it needs to be. If you need to pass a variable, do it in an anonymous function:

```
$(document).on('submit','#site-search', function() {
    searchOperator.controller.searchStart(searchOperator.model.page)
});
```

@Adeneo's comment sums it up nicely: Adding the parenthesis calls the function, just using the name of the function references the function.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for.